# Javascript added form elements not being added to array

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a simple Javascript that adds text boxes to a form. It appears to work (i.e. a new box is added to the form) but when I submit the new form elements are not added to the array. So only the info in the first text box is submitted. Here is the code.

HTML

```
<div id="dynamicInput">
      Part SKU 1: <input type="text" name="myInputs[]">
 </div>
 <input type="button" value="Add Another Part" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
```

JS

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 5;
function addInput(divName){
 if (counter == limit)  {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
 }
 else {
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = "Part " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input id='input"+(counter + 1)+"' type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
      document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
      counter++;
 }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your input name must be unique otherwise it will grab the first one and leave out the rest similar to how JS treats ID's

Comment: I don't understand. If I hard code in another text box with the same name it adds the second info to the array as it should. Why are the text boxes created by JS not working?

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle or something showing the working static version and they dynamic version which is not working.